# json-php giving filed out put two times?

Tags: php, json

There is records about the login_ids in json array. I want to fetch required results in json-php decode function. It is giving the login_id two times on top and bottom for each row. I there any way not to print the login_id in the value filed?  The code details are given below.

```
<?php
    $json = '{"records" : 
       [
            {
                "Name": "Jhon",
                "Age": "45",
                "Place": "Kettle",
                "Phone": "9834453",
                "log_id": "216" 
            },
            {
                "Name": "Bill",
                "Age": "41",
                "Place": "Ottava",
                "Phone": "4513453",
                "log_id": "215"         
        },
            {
               "Name": "James",
                "Age": "39",
                "Place": "Mexico",
                "Phone": "3456734",
                "log_id": "217" 
            },
        {
            "Name": "larry",
                "Age": "51",
                "Place": "New city",
                "Phone": "34890453",
                "log_id": "213" 
        }
        ]
    }';

$myjson = json_decode($json, true);  // decode the json string to an array
  foreach ( $myjson['records'] as $row ) {  // loop the records
            echo 'Details of  login id:&nbsp;'.  $row['log_id']. '<br/>';
            foreach ( $row as $field => $value ) {  // loop the fields
            echo  $field . ': '. $value . '<br>';
            }
         echo '<br/>'; 
    }
?>
```

Also is there any simple method to print the required login id (i.e where the login_id="217") so that the address of one person is given out put.

Comment: add if condition to skip the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code my be better but not tested.

```
foreach ( $myjson['records'] as $row ) {  
        if ($row['log_id'] =='216') { // login id to be checked
               echo 'Details of  login id:&nbsp;'.  $row['log_id']. '<br/>';
               foreach ( $row as $field => $value ) {  // loop the fields
                    if ($field != "log_id") { // hide the login id t bottom           
                           echo $field . ': ' . $value . '<br>';
                           }
              }
              echo '<br/>'; 
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Test the field name before printing it.

```
foreach ($row as $field => $value {
    if ($field != "log_id") {
        echo $field . ': ' . $value . '<br>';
    }
}
```